# How to create a great design using twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, frontend

As a developer mainly focused on programming the backend, sometimes I find it very difficult to create nice designs. I have used twitter bootstrap, but even with it my designs are not very appealing.

Do you have rules of thumb for creating nice design using bootstrap?

I'm more interested in knowing the process that you follow.

Comment: "Nice" is an ambiguous concept. You should outline what is "Nice" to you. Then we can weight in on how to accomplish that

Comment: Ok, nice is ambiguous, with nice I mean:
- Have a good combination of colors
- How do you choose the backgrounds
- Which layouts you use

I'm more interested in the process that others developers follow and seeing examples. As my background is not design any insight is useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about styling, not about actual programming. (Even if it is about styling using Twitter Bootstrap, the underlying question is still about looks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some Web Graphic Design stuff is here

http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/designing-tutorials/9-essential-principles-for-good-web-design/

Some Free Bootstrap Themes

http://bootswatch.com/#gallery

Comment: This is the kind of thing I'm looking for, sometimes you just don't know what to search for in Google, so this answer my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have the best results using a theme: https://wrapbootstrap.com/, or a theme roller: http://bootswatchr.com/

Comment: I checked them, they look nice. Thank you